# Power draw increases significantly after plugging in to AC

Tags: power-management, asus, 20.10, charging

I am running ubuntu 20.10 on an Asus Zephyrus G14. I have the GPU disabled and I set the power governor for each core to 'powersave' with a bash script when I startup. With normal load (Web browsing, code editors open but no big programs running) I draw about 7w give or take 1 watt as reported by powerstat -d 0 (battery only).

However, as soon as I plug into a charger the laptop gets very hot (from cool metal to like a warm shower level of hot). I can't measure the power draw when I'm plugged in- but with my 45W USB-C charger, the battery actually discharges to meet the power demand, rather than charging.
When I look at htop, I don't see anything particularly out of the ordinary, and the power governor hasn't changed, so I am really at a loss as to why it is discharging so much- and what is actually drawing all the power.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Does the screen go brighter when you plug it in?

Comment: Just tested, and the screen seems to stay on whatever setting I had it on before

Comment: I open nvidia-xserver settings and select Intel (Power Saving Mode).  When I try nvidia-smi in this mode it tells me it couldn't communicate with the nvidia-driver, so it appears it is working properly, especially considering the battery life I get.

Comment: If it's not a matter of power management configuration, it should be a problem with drivers. There are several cases of battery load issues.